# Stack Exchange Bug Bounty Program

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

What do you guys think about a Bug Bounty Program for the Stack Exchange sites?

Instead of cash, rewards could be reputation points, and we could have a ranking and a hall of fame too.

This would attract the attention of a lot of security researchers, and could contribute positively to the security of the entire community.

Comment: See the responses from SEI in comments to this: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/814/33